# What is the concept behind the "Shake your head" images to see a different image behind the straight bars image

Tags: image, image-processing

I see these king of images many times:

[image]

You shake your head and you can find an image hidden behind these bars.

I want to understand the concept behind this. And how can I create something of this sort on my own.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it's explained here http://thilinasameera.wordpress.com/2012/04/12/photo-effects-using-matlab-2-0-optical-illusion-using-matlab-shake-your-head-and-see-the-image/